# Show ContextMenuStripItem without clicking off the current cell

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using an `UltraGrid` which has a `ContextMenuStrip` with 2 items. These are shown when right-clicking an `UltraGridCell`.

However, in order to show them, the user has to first click off the cell to take it out of edit mode, then right click on it to show the `ContextMenuStripItems`.

This has become confusing and irritating to the user, so I was wondering if there is any way that it can be changed to show them when right clicking whilst still in edit mode?

I've tried this to take it out of edit mode after a key is pressed, but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub ugComm_keyup(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ugComm.KeyUp

  ugComm.UpdateData()
  If ugComm.ActiveCell.IsInEditMode = True Then
      ugComm.ActiveCell.Row.Update()
  End If

End Sub
```

I also tried something in the `MouseClick` that was suggested on the Infragistics forums, but again it didn't work.

Is there any way that a user right-clicking a cell that is in edit mode can bring up the `ContextMenuStripItems` rather than this menu?
[image]

The above image shows what is currently show when right-clicking a cell in edit mode (The cell is the bottom right white cell). I don't want this to appear, but the CMS instead.

**EDIT**

I've tried the suggestions in the current answers, but neither of those worked for me. Possibly because the grids are a slightly older version?

My most recent effort was done with the following code:

```
Private Sub ugComm_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ugComm.MouseDown

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Me.cmCommRate.Show(mouseX, mouseY)
    End If
End Sub
```

But this wasn't triggered until the cell was no longer in edit mode.

**NEITHER OF THE ANSWERS BELOW RESOLVE THE ISSUE. STILL NEEDS AN ANSWER**

Comment: As explained in the answers below this is expected to work. I suppose that if you have problems with this basic standard functionality, something on your  side is not quite as it is expected to be. Perhaps you could try to reproduce your problem in a separate project and post this project somewhere on the net to let use check on it. If you follow this path be sure to have the grid with the exact properties you have in your current project. And be sure to tell us which version of Infragistics control are you using.

Comment: @Steve I've whipped up a quick test project with just one form and DB table which replicates two issues I'm having. The first one is the issue I described above, right-clicking a cell whilst in edit mode isn't showing the `ContextMenuStrip`. The second issue is that in the date columns, it doesn't allow selection of the current date. I've uploaded it to my Google Drive, which you can find here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_ky_lDrWKlZSHp5Q0xCM1QyUUE

Comment: @Steve Worth noting, the project doesn't include the code you suggested, but I've tried both of the answers and it's not worked with either.

Comment: That's challenging. Infragistics.2005 v1. It is stuff from twelve years ago. I will look if I still have a copy around of those bits.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, appreciate that. I'm not sure why as a company we use such an old version, I guess it's to do with saving money on upgrading.

Comment: @Steve Did you have any luck at all?

Comment: Nope, in office tomorrow perhaps.

Comment: @Steve Okay, I've awarded the bounty to you since you've provided an answer and looked further into it, so if you're able to offer any advice after a further look tomorrow that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When any cell of the grid enters in edit mode a TextBox is drawn over the cell. The nice part here is this text box is reused for all the cells in the grid. When you right click on the cell in edit mode the default context menu, that comes from MS, shows. What you need to do is get this text box and assign it your context menu strip. You can do this by handling ControlAdded event of the grid like this:

```
    ' create a field to store the TextBox    
    Private cellTextBox As TextBox

    Private Sub grid_ControlAdded(sender As Object, e As ControlEventArgs) Handles grid.ControlAdded
        ' Check if added control is TextBox 
        If TypeOf e.Control Is TextBox Then
            ' If added control is TextBox store it in your private field and set its ContextMenuStrip
            If Me.cellTextBox Is Nothing Then
                Me.cellTextBox = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
                Me.cellTextBox.ContextMenuStrip = Me.ctx
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I've only just had a chance to look at this - No, this hasn't solved it either. The usual menu comes up as shown in the image. Must be something to do with the grid

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This is related to the grid. If you set grid's context menu to point to an instance of ContextMenu, like this Me.ugComm.ContextMenu = YOUR_CONTRXT_MENU, it will show this menu in the grid, including in cell in edit mode. However, you said you did this and it did not work. This is why I had shown you how to replace the cell editor TextBox's context menu. I tested both these in one of my grids and both way works. Are you setting the grid's context menu to NOTHING somewhere in your application? This will "return" the default menu of the TextBox.

Comment: This is `ContextMenuStrip` rather than a `ContextMenu`, if that makes any difference?

Comment: Additionally, it may be worth nothing that this works when selecting items from a drop down list cell (Value list, where typing is disabled), but not for cells where the value is typed in.

Comment: I've created a test project to replicate this behaviour, found on the link below. There is nothing that I can see that would cause this issue. It doesn't include the code you've added here, but after testing it it doesn't work even with it. Any chance you could have a look? Also, the date columns don't accept the current date to be selected too, which is weird. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ky_lDrWKlZSHp5Q0xCM1QyUUE/view

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to write an event handler for the MouseUp event with this code

```
Private Sub grid_MouseUp(sender As Object, e as MouseEventArgs) Handles grid.KeyUp
    grid.PerformAction(UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode)
    grid.ContextMenuStrip.Show()
End Sub
```

and it works.

The ContextMenuStrip was added in code with this text (as example)

```
ContextMenuStrip ctx = new ContextMenuStrip()
ctx.Items.Add("Test1")
ctx.Items.Add("Test2")
ctx.Items.Add("Test3")
grid.ContextMenuStrip = ctx
```

Comment: This only works if I change to a different cell, and then try it, but doesn't seem to work if I type a value then click it again directly without activating another cell.

Comment: Uhm not in my experience. If I right click on a cell in edit mode, the custom menu strip appears and it appears also if I right click anywhere in the grid. Is it possible that some other events is messing with the cell?

Comment: Is there anything else that it could be? Something about the grid version? Another property?

Comment: The event doesn't even fire when I try it whilst it's in edit mode

Comment: I don't know what could be the problem. Here, with version 2011.2  it works perfectly albeit I have written the same code in C# inside LinqPad. However I have a vanilla grid without any property set automatically through the WinForms designer (just a declare UltraGrid grid = new UltraGrid() and then setting the event handler and a datasource)

Comment: In the meantime. Tried your code with Infragistics 2015 and the context menu appears when the cell is in edit mode. Crashes though after selecting the single menu item because _cmsVatRate.Parent_ is Nothing

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case in the actual project or not, I think I did set the parent. Could setting/not setting the parent be the issue behind showing it in edit mode?

Comment: I have managed to install the version 2005.3 (not the 2005.1) and I can confirm that your problem exists also in that version. When the cell is in edit mode you don't see your custom menu but just the standard context menu. So, somewhere after that point in time, Infragistics changed this behavior and now (2011) you could get your contextmenu also inside a cell in edit mode. I can't be more precise about the timeframe when this change occurred. You should probably ask their support if any hotfixes after the initial release of 2005.1 is available to you with this change included.

Comment: Thanks Steve, at least it's an issue with the grids, rather than my code. I'm assuming that the age of the grids is also why date columns don't accept the current date, without first choosing an past or future date? Are you aware of any way around this at all?

Comment: By the way, the workaround posted by @wnvko works but only on Text fields not on DateTime fields. Probably because these fields use a different 'editor' to handle dates. With some debug and looking at the editor field of the cell I think you could make it work also for dates field. For the dates problem I am sorry but I have no idea.

Comment: I've not managed to make @wnvko's answer work when right-clicking a Text field cell. It worked in the `ControlAdded` subroutine when opening a `ValueList` cell, but not when right-clicking a Text cell that was in edit mode. Even on `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`, the event isn't fired.